# "ghost line" on page load in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

This is driving my mad... In Chrome my page leaves a black line exactly at the bottom of the page when loaded. It's visible when you scroll down.

Here is a link tot the page: http://www.white-board.be/kaartings.php

I don't have this issue on other pages of my website. I tried changing css-settings, without succes.

The odd thing is, that when I do a crtl-refresh, the line is never there. Does anyone have an idea of what micht be causing this?

In IE, Firefox and Safari I have no problems at all.

edit: screenshot (I have the same problem at work and at home, win XP and win7)
chrom version: 26.0.1410.64 m

[image: only visible when you scroll down after page load]

Comment: I can't see any black line. Do you have a screen shot?

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on OS X with Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Comment: Try to remove `html { height: 100%;}`

Comment: that fixes the black line issue! But then again.. I need this to be at 100% for the other pages, otherwise my footer doenst stay at the bottom of the page (when there is not enough content to fill the page completely)

Comment: No black line here. Chrome 26.0.1410.64m, Windows 7.

Comment: By the way, did you know that your page doesnt load completely in compatibility view (IE10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found out what was causing this. For some reason (don't ask me where I got it from or why i thought i needed this) the following line in my css body setting made the problem occur:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Deleting it, solved it.

Thanks alot for the responses!